# Правописание «не» с союзом «но» без прямого противопоставления

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Нужно ли во фразе "Небольшой его фанат, но с этого посмеялся" писать "не" раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основной принцип правила следующий:
**НЕ + ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ = ПРОТИВОПОЛОЖНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ — ПИШЕМ СЛИТНО.**
**НЕ + ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ = ОТСУТСТВИЕ ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКИ — ПИШЕМ РАЗДЕЛЬНО.**

Если писать ‟небольшой”, то это то же самое, что и ‟маленький”, — например: ‟Я увидел небольшой домик в лесу”, ‟Мой оклад небольшой, но я доволен”. Можно говорить ‟я большой фанат”, но нельзя говорить ‟я небольшой фанат”, так как нельзя быть чуть-чуть фанатом. Такое написание может оправдываться в определенном контексте каким-нибудь фигуральным приемом, но тут такого фигурального приема определенно нет. В итоге, правильно будет так: **‟Не большой его фанат, но с этого посмеялся”.** Вот парочка примеров из Нац. корпуса:

> Я, конечно, не большой специалист, но мне кажется, что все в мире разумно, и вряд ли бы было возможно такое, чтобы тоннель во времени походил на проходной двор. [Кусчуй Непома. Там-машин // «Волга», 2014]

> Володя, возможно, не большой знаток женского пола, но неглупый человек, он давно усвоил: если девушка мрачно молчит, лучше ее ни о чем не спрашивать. [Алексей Слаповский. Большая Книга Перемен // «Волга», 2010]